# Direct access to object key from type

Tags: typescript

Considering the following interface :

```
interface StateEntry {
    [state: string]: {metaState: string}
}
```

With objects always having the same shape such as :

```
{NEW: {metaState: "ACTIVE"}}
```

I have an array of such objects (such as `const arr = [state1, state2, state3]`, how can I directly access the unique `state` value from `arr[0]`?

Something as `arr[0].state === 'NEW'`

I think doing `Objects.keys(arr[0])[0]` is fairly unelegant.

Should I change the interface ?

Answer (score 0):

Use For..each to iterate the array and For..in to iterate each object

Ex: For..in loop.

For(const key in arrayName) => console.log(key)

Comment: In that case `console.log(key)` will print the index. If you want to print the object use for of

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is only one key per entry object, you may change your interface:

```js
interface StateEntry {
    type: string
    metaState: string
}
```

The value would be:

```js
{ type: "NEW", metaState: "ACTIVE" }
```

Accessing the type would be:

```js
arr[0].type
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

`Object.keys(arr[0])[0]`

for your example

```
interface StateEntry {
  [state: string]: { metaState: string }
}
const state1: StateEntry = { NEW: { metaState: "ACTIVE" } }
const state2: StateEntry = { NEW: { metaState: "ACTIVE" } }

const arr: StateEntry[]= [state1,state2]

console.log(Object.keys(arr[0])[0])
```

[full example in TypeScript playGround](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAlgdgLgpgTgMwIYGMYAIDKUmwKLRwCe6A3qOugNoDOOsAXOnXJAOYC6Tp6AtjDmy4YTFu3QBfUFJAoA9hDrN6MAIxMh%20QiQC8ZdADk8AdW58BSTSPQAiAIIBhACoBJAGp4bkyaHmKoysIATBoqBFDE6Ho8Rqb6-IIqTPbO7p7eMr4KSkhwcKHC4cRUHHq0KqoANHTBHKBZinIANjAAdE1ybAAUAPIARgBWMChQrQDWMEQ0XblwVAAMHACUC8ugQA)